# Use PHP/Jquery to drag and drop files to attach to email

Tags: php, jquery

Im trying to create a very simple ticketing system.  In a nutshell it goes like this:

A user fills out some HTML form fields, attaches between one and three files via file upload.  On submit the form and its contents are submitted via post to a PHP script that creates an email with the form data and the files attached.

I dont need the files to be uploaded to the server, but if required for this process, there would be advantages to keeping them on the server.

Jquery drag and drop would be my preference, but a simple HTML input type="file" would be fine.

Basically my question is this; how do I go about attaching the files to the email from form fields?  Can I feed the input type="file" straight into the PHP email sending script?  Or do I need to upload them to a physical location on my server and then attach a link to that file to the email?

Comment: I use https://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/ to store the file on server ..  And then use `mailto` to send said file to recipient.

Comment: can only send them from server where email is sent from

Comment: It isnt necessary to send from the server but I prefer it.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: that was a statement, attachments need to be on same server